# How to get rid of the black ground on the image returned from UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage when using UIImagePicker

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

When using UIImagePicker, it allows to get into Edit mode. Then for an image taken with landscape mode, if user don't scale it manually within the UIImagePicker, there would have black stripe/background on the top and bottom of the image. Is there a way to get rid of that and make that portion of the image to be transparent?

Answer (score 2):

```
#pragma mark UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *img = nil;

    CGRect cropRect = [[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerCropRect] CGRectValue];

    if (cropRect.origin.y < 0) {

        img = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    } else {

        img = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

    }

}
```