# Image returned from UIImagePickerController goes beyond edge of image, adds black bar

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I have users select an image from the UIImagePickerController and when I access the image afterwards, it has a black bar. Note the image is not cropped, the image picker actually goes beyond the bounds of the image where no pixels exist and adds empty blackspace.

My code:

```
@IBAction func selectImageButt(_ sender: Any) {
    let imagepicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagepicker.allowsEditing = true
    imagepicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    imagepicker.delegate = self
    present(imagepicker, animated: true)
}
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
        testImageView.image = image
    }
    picker.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

The results are as follows:

[image]

Note I've tried changing the image view's `contentMode` to scale to fill as well as aspect fill (not fit). I don't know why the black bars are added as part of the image itself. Can anybody assist?
[image]

Comment: change **UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage** to **UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage** ??

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to leave `allowsEditing` on. Updated the question.

Comment: I'd isolate the issue to the UIImage, or the UIImageView. Put a breakpoint at `testImageView.image = image` and quicklook the `image` to see if it has the black bar or not.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I had the same problem.

Comment: my problem is same and I got some solution but it did not work for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/13813738/1606492

Comment: I don't think there is a solid solution... I think it was just an issue with the APIs.

Comment: @EmanHarout, Did you found any solution for this issue? Currently, I'm also getting the same issue on the iPhone 6 Plus and iPhone X. But it is working fine on some other devices.

Comment: Unfortunately I never did find a solution to this. Wish I had better news.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this issue by use original image if the cropped image is out side the origin

```
guard let selectedImage = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage else {
        fatalError("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
    }

var image = selectedImage
 if let cropRect = info[.cropRect] as? CGRect {
     if cropRect.origin.y < 0 {
          guard let imageOrigin = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
              fatalError("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
          }
          image = imageOrigin
      }

 }
```